# How to set parent path of $(SRCROOT) in Xcode

Tags: xcode

From the http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38, we can find Xcode's build settings like $(SRCROOT). But in my case, the header files is in a parent folder of $(SRCROOT). Is there a way to access that without put in the absolute path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The sequence `..` refers to the parent directory in almost all operating systems.

```
$(SRCROOT)/../OtherPath
```

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work for me. My project is at ~myUser/MainProject/XcodeProject/test.xcodeproj. And there is a include path at ~myUser/MainProject/includes. Using what you suggested $(SRCROOT)/../includes, in Xcode Header Search Paths setting, Xcode explained it as  ~myUser/MainProject/XcodeProject/../includes, not ~myUser/MainProject/includes. And compile can't find the include files under ~myUser/MainProject/includes/. BTW, I am using Xcode 4.5.2. on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Well, I take it back. After delete the Xcode project, re-create a new one and using Jim's suggestion and now it works. Thanks a lot!